# Managing User Permissions with IdentityServer 4

Tags: permissions, identityserver4

Currently I am building my project with ASP.NET Core and using Identity Server 4 as my authentication engine.
I am trying to manage user permissions using IdentityServer. 
I saw that scopes are defined per client not per user, so I wonder how can I manage user permissions per action.
Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Check the comments and answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54006026/open-id-connect-doubts-identity-server-4-how-to-grant-specific-users-to-con

Comment: Thanks a lot I will check it out :)

Answer (score 2):

IS4 is an authentication framework (almost). For role-based access control and attribute-based access control you need to build authorization framework. you can check this repo to get better idea how to implement it: https://github.com/Xabaril/Balea