# IdentityServer4 User scopes/rights/claims?

Tags: authentication, identityserver4, scopes

I'm trying to use the identityserver4 for authentication and some access rights and how would I do it the right way?

I want to specify, for every api I have, specific scopes. Like every api should have scopes like "read_only", "write_only" and "full_access". Some should have some more specific ones. Now I want to connect those scopes with users.

So I can configure User A has these rights: api1.read_only, api2.full_access
and User B these: api1.full_access, api2.custom_one

Now the problem I'm facing is that I never specify any scopes to a user but to a client. After a little bit of research I found out that an client represents an application and that this application has specific rights rather than the user.

But creating a client for every scope I define in my api is probably a really bad way.

Now I hope some of you guys can help me out with some informations on how to do it properly.

Comment: A scope has nothing to do with permissions. A scope is a reference to a piece of functionality within the resource. Please read my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54006026/open-id-connect-doubts-identity-server-4-how-to-grant-specific-users-to-con/54016213#54016213).

Comment: in brief, the **scope is the right of an application** to access some api function. the **permission is the right of some application's user** to perform the action, so you need to check both.